# Notification for facebook app requests not showing up

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

I created an application for a website and gave it a site url.  (The site url is actually not real.  It is overridden in my local hostname file for development purposes.  Does this matter?).

I used the [sample code for creating a request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to send requests to another facebook account.  I used the multi-user interface, without the to: field.  When I refresh the page in my other facebook account, I see a red 1 on the world icon for just a split second, but then it disappears and there is no notification to be found.  It does this every time I send a request.  Is there something wrong with my requests that they are getting deleted instantly?  Have I configured my app wrong in some way?

Comment: Can you show us relevant part of your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have had the exact same problem, I was able to fix this by entering a url in the Website part of https://developers.facebook.com/apps apps basic information, add an app domain and a canvas url ... i suspect it will work with only the canvas url since this is the url where the notification links to.

hope it helps,

cheers!

Comment: But that's under the "App on Facebook" section.  I guess I have to enable that too if I wanna send requests.  Thanks :D

Comment: I am also facing issue of not getting notifications but in my case, I am sending invitation from my website through facebook to my friends and request is showing up in app center requests without any notification. Defining canvas url will show my website under facebook but ideally it should redirect back to my website when I click on the notification.any idea?